# How to add meta data to a video in c++

Tags: c++, video, metadata

I want to add metadata to each frame of a video using C++ (To give a id to each frame to identify them separately). How can I do it and is there any library to do so?

Comment: https://www.ffmpeg.org/

Comment: Can I have an example code please.. I want to add and retrieve metadata from each frame..
Thanx in advance!!